# How to save images generated as output in Colab in google drive?

Tags: image

I have executed a code to generate about 100 images in Colab. Now I want to save these images in a folder in google drive. How can I do that?

I tried to directly copy the images but it did not work. I can save the images in my pc and then upload them, but I have to save them individually, but I want to save the images together.